oidc config not working when upgrading to v12 angular
i'm currently upgrading the angular version to v12 and the oidc config is not working or not able to redirect to the login page. below is the app.module.ts file the comment out code is how we use the config in v11
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  AuthModule,
  LogLevel,
  OidcConfigService,
  OidcSecurityService,
  OpenIdConfiguration,
} from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';
import { NgDynamicBreadcrumbModule } from 'ng-dynamic-breadcrumb';
import { AddressCompareComponent } from './address-compare/address-compare.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthorizationGuard } from './authorization.guard';
import { AutoLoginComponent } from './auto-login/auto-login.component';
import { SimpleConfirmationDialogComponent } from './common/simple-confirmation-dialog.component';
import { SnackBarComponent } from './common/snack-bar.component';
import { TitleTranslationsCardComponent } from './common/title-translations-card.component';
import { TreeNodeComponent } from './common/tree-node.component';
import { TwoCollapsiblePanelsComponent } from './common/two-collapsible-panels.component';
import { DashboardInsuredComponent } from './dashboard-insured/dashboard-insured.component';
import { DashboardLocationComponent } from './dashboard-location/dashboard-location.component';
import { DashboardTasksComponent } from './dashboard-tasks/dashboard-tasks.component';
import { PendingHandoverComponent } from './dashboard-tasks/pending-handover/pending-handover.component';
import { TaskDetailsComponent } from './dashboard-tasks/pending-handover/task-details/task-details.component';
import { PendingTasksComponent } from './dashboard-tasks/pending-tasks/pending-tasks.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ForbiddenComponent } from './forbidden/forbidden.component';
import { HeaderBarComponent } from './header/header-bar.component';
import { InsuranceCaseComponent } from './insurance-case/insurance-case.component';
import { InsuranceSearchComponent } from './insurance-search/insurance-search.component';
import { AddEditnewLocationComponent } from './insurance/add-edit-new-location/add-edit-new-location.component';
import { InsuranceLocationComponent } from './insurance/insurance-location/insurance-location.component';
import { LocationFilterComponent } from './insurance/location-filter/location-filter.component';
import { LogComponent } from './log/log.component';
import { DemoMaterialModule } from './material-module';
import { ReportsEditFormComponent } from './reports/reports-edit-form/reports-edit-form.component';
import { ReportsComponent } from './reports/reports.component';
import { KeynewIndicatorComponent } from './new/key-new-indicator.component';
import { newIndicatorComponent } from './new/new-indicator.component';
import { newTreeTemplateDetailComponent } from './new/new-tree-template-detail/new-tree-template-detail.component';
import { newTreeTemplateFormComponent } from './new/new-tree-template-form/new-tree-template-form.component';
import { newTreeTemplateComponent } from './new/new-tree-template/new-tree-template.component';
import { newTreeComponent } from './new/new-tree.component';
import { newTreesComponent } from './new/new-trees.component';
import { APIInterceptor } from './service/baseUrlInterceptor.service';
import { CommonService, OidcConfig } from './service/common.service';
import { DataService } from './service/data.service';
import { SharedStateFullModule } from './shared-state-full/shared-state-full.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { TabDirectiveAutoCompleteDirective } from './tab-directive-auto-complete.directive';
import { TitleTranslateDirective } from './title-translate.directive';
import { UnauthorizedComponent } from './unauthorized/unauthorized.component';
import { EditIndustryTemplateComponent } from './edit-industry-template/edit-industry-template.component';
 
// export function oidcConfigServiceFactory(
//   oidcConfigService: OidcConfigService,
//   commonService: CommonService
// ) {
//   return async () => {
//     await commonService.init();
//     const config = commonService.getAppConfig().oidcConfig;
//     return oidcConfigService.withConfigs({
//       authority: config?.stsServer,
//       authWellknownEndpoint: config?.authWellknownEndpoint,
//       redirectUrl: window.location.origin,
//       clientId: config?.clientId,
//       scope: `${config?.scope} offline_access`,
//       responseType: 'code',
//       triggerAuthorizationResultEvent: true,
//       postLogoutRedirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/unauthorized`,
//       startCheckSession: false,
//       silentRenew: true,
//       silentRenewUrl: window.location.origin + '/silent-renew.html',
//       postLoginRoute: '/home',
//       forbiddenRoute: '/forbidden',
//       unauthorizedRoute: '/unauthorized',
//       logLevel: LogLevel.Warn,
//       historyCleanupOff: true,
//       useRefreshToken: true,
//       autoUserinfo: false,
//       renewTimeBeforeTokenExpiresInSeconds: 60,
//       maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds: 600,
//       ignoreNonceAfterRefresh: true,
//     });
//   };
// }

const oidcConfiguration = () => {
  let commonService: CommonService;
  commonService.init();
 
  return commonService.getAppConfig().oidcConfig;
}
 
 
export let AppInjector: Injector;
 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TwoCollapsiblePanelsComponent,
    HeaderBarComponent,
    AppComponent,
    newTreesComponent,
    newTreeComponent,
    KeynewIndicatorComponent,
    newIndicatorComponent,
    TreeNodeComponent,
    TitleTranslationsCardComponent,
    LogComponent,
    SimpleConfirmationDialogComponent,
    SnackBarComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    InsuranceCaseComponent,
    InsuranceLocationComponent,
    AddEditnewLocationComponent,
    LocationFilterComponent,
    TitleTranslateDirective,
    TabDirectiveAutoCompleteDirective,
    AutoLoginComponent,
    ForbiddenComponent,
    UnauthorizedComponent,
    newTreeTemplateComponent,
    newTreeTemplateDetailComponent,
    newTreeTemplateFormComponent,
    AddressCompareComponent,
    InsuranceSearchComponent,
    DashboardLocationComponent,
    DashboardInsuredComponent,
    DashboardTasksComponent,
    TaskDetailsComponent,
    PendingTasksComponent,
    PendingHandoverComponent,
    ReportsComponent,
    ReportsEditFormComponent,
    EditIndustryTemplateComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        authority: oidcConfiguration()?.stsServer,  // Use dynamic config here
        authWellknownEndpointUrl: oidcConfiguration()?.authWellknownEndpoint,
        redirectUrl: window.location.origin,
        clientId: oidcConfiguration()?.clientId,
        scope: `${oidcConfiguration()?.scope} offline_access`,
        responseType: 'code',
        triggerAuthorizationResultEvent: true,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/unauthorized`,
        startCheckSession: false,
        silentRenew: true,
        silentRenewUrl: window.location.origin + '/silent-renew.html',
        postLoginRoute: '/home',
        forbiddenRoute: '/forbidden',
        unauthorizedRoute: '/unauthorized',
        logLevel: LogLevel.Warn,
        historyCleanupOff: true,
        useRefreshToken: true,
        autoUserInfo: false,
        renewTimeBeforeTokenExpiresInSeconds: 60,
        maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds: 600,
        ignoreNonceAfterRefresh: true,
      },
    }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    NgDynamicBreadcrumbModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    SharedStateFullModule,
  ],
 
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'de-DE' },
    DataService,
    OidcSecurityService,
    OidcConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: oidcConfiguration,
      deps: [OidcConfigService, CommonService],
      multi: true,
    },
    AuthorizationGuard,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: APIInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    AppInjector = this.injector;
  }
}

the error on the console that I'm getting
main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'init')

I'm new to angular and unable to resolve this I followed this migration guide migration guide
but unable to resolve the error
init method
 init() {
console.log('Loading application configuration');
return this.httpClient
  .get<AppConfig>('./config.json')
  .toPromise()
  .then((config) => {
    this.appConfig = config;
  });

}

why have you commented oidcConfigServiceFactory that should  be set on the APP_INITIALIZER

oh yes earlier in v11 oidcConfigServiceFactory  was set in APP_INITIALIZER and AuthModule.forRoot() was just a method but in v12 we have to write config in AuthModule.forRoot so have to comment out "oidcConfigServiceFactory"

can you share the code of init method?

added the init code
